# extern template declaration with alias payload

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, extern, explicit-instantiation

Consider this. There is a class `Derived` that inherits from some instantiation of a heavy templated class `Base`, and there are many uses of `Derived` in various source files. So it is reasonable to have only one `Derived`-specific instantiation of `Base`.

C++11 allows this via `extern template`, but the problem here is that I want to type the `Derived`-specific instantiation of `Base` only once. Technically it is possible, as `Derived` can hold an alias for that instantiation, but the question is: will it still force the compiler not to instantiate the template?

Here is the try:

```
// Base.hpp
template < typename Arg > struct Base { using TheArg = Arg; };

// Derived.hpp
#include "Base.hpp"
struct Derived : Base<int> { };
// The next line will be huge in real-world scenario, so I want to avoid it.
// extern template struct Base<int>;
// Instead I want this.
extern template struct Base<Derived::TheArg>;

// Derived.cpp
#include "Derived.hpp"
template struct Base<Derived::TheArg>;

// Use01.cpp
#include "Derived.hpp"
void use01() { Derived dd; }
```

The point here is to force `Use01.cpp` not to instantiate `Base<int>` and to refer to the explicit instantiation at `Derived.cpp` instead.

I am compiling with `gcc-v9.3` and the questions are:

1. Does `extern template` declaration takes effect to all instantiations in the translation unit, or only to those which appear *after* its declaration?
2. Will using `Derived::TheArg` instead of `int` cause any problems with deferring the instantiation?

Putting the `extern template` declaration at the end of `Use01.cpp` and commenting out the explicit instantiation at `Derived.cpp` makes the compilation to fail, so this gives me some confidence that the `extern template` declaration doesn't have to appear before any instantiation, so the second question still makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explicit instantiation declaration of a specialization of a class template **doesn’t** prevent instantiating that specialization.  After all, you still need to be able to refer to members of the resulting class, which means knowing everything about its layout.  What it does do is prevent instantiation of its (non-inline) member **functions**, so that no code need be emitted for them.

Additionally, an explicit instantiation declaration must **precede** any source of implicit instantiation to be effective.  If you want to name that specialization’s template argument just once, introduce a type alias for it before the explicit instantiation declaration *and* the definition of `Derived`.